# Inject Folder ID from selection in GDrive Addon and suppress cardflip

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get the scope of gdrive to create a file from some form values with my addon.
To achieve this, I added a handler to the manifest and implemented the corresponding function.

```
      "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "onDriveItemsSelected"
  }
```

In the function I can use the following as ID of the first selected item. (I currently check Mimetype to keep it simple...)

```
    createFolderID = e['drive']['selectedItems'][0].id;
```

Now I have two problems:

1.
When clicking a folder within the gdrive - the event function seems to await a built card as return value. I just want to use the selected folder (or ideally the folder where I am currently "in", via getparent?), without needing an additional card. If I return null, the card is created anyway above my addon card and shown with "No content shown for this message".
Is there away to avoid this?

2.
I need to inject the folder ID of the selected folder into my form (which I created with CardService at start of the addon). Declaring a "global" var does not seem to work,I assume that the cloud context will not preserve the variable value. The value is needed as parameter to a created document of my addon.

Can anyone point me into the right direction to store this folder Id until the user runs the addons action?

EDIT:

```
/**
 * Get the selected folder to create the offer in
 */
function onDriveItemsSelected(e) {
// We check only the first selection
  if (e['drive']['selectedItems'][0].mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
  {
    createFolderTitle = e['drive']['selectedItems'][0].title;
    createFolderID = e['drive']['selectedItems'][0].id;
    Logger.log(e['drive']['selectedItems'][0].title + " selected. ID: " + createFolderID)
      PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('selectedFolderId', createFolderID);
  }
}
```

The following snippet is contained in the manifest to link the function to selection events.

```
"drive": {
  "homepageTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "initForm"
  },
  "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "onDriveItemsSelected"
  }
}
```

I use this for catching the selection event. But the card on the right side is then overlayed with an empty card with the message I already mentioned.

Comment: You could use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) top store the selected folder Id.Then you can fetch it when creating the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pass a default parameter to a function.

### Example:

```js
function createForm(selectedFolderId = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("selectedFolderId")) {
  let form;
  // Create the form
  return form;
}
```

### References:

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)

---

### Update:

When you use [OnItemsSelectedTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/drive-addons#onitemsselectedtrigger) you **must** return an array of Card objects.

Comment: Great! This solves my "id storage problem". I clear the stored ID after creating my document to avoid users being confused if they dont remember where they were lastly. Any idea about questiuon 1?

Comment: I have trouble reproducing your first question. Can you share the minimal code to do so?